# How to find orphaned records that point to different tables (paramerization required)?

Tags: sql, t-sql, recursion, with-statement

Table ( A ) has a 1-1 relation with many tables ( B, C, D, ... ) and is defined by two columns:

- `ObjectType(nvarchar(100))`  // name of the other table
- `_Guid(uniqueidentifier)`     // record ID in the other table

Additionally, all tables contain an `IsDeleted(bit)` column.

The question is:

How to list all the records from (A) that point to non-existing record in B, C, D, (...) OR to the record that has `IsDeleted = 1` set?

The following will not work because `ObjectType` must be a parameter:

```
SELECT ObjectType, _Guid FROM A
where 
    NOT EXISTS (
        select * from ObjectType where oid = _Guid
    )
```

The following will also not work:

```
SELECT ObjectType, _Guid FROM A
where 
    NOT EXISTS (
        exec('select * from '+ObjectType+' where oid =''' + _Guid + '''')
    )
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This terrible SQL below seems to work:

```
DECLARE @A_tmpTable TABLE (
    idx smallint Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1)
    , ObjectType nvarchar(200)
    , _Guid nvarchar(100)
    , Oid nvarchar(100)
)
DECLARE @orphanedA_tmpTable TABLE (
    Oid nvarchar(100)
)
DECLARE @_objectType nvarchar(200)
DECLARE @_Guid nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @_oid nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @i int, @numrows int  
DECLARE @found bit

-- populate temp table
INSERT @A_tmpTable SELECT ObjectType, _Guid, Oid FROM A WHERE IsDeleted = 0
--SELECT * FROM @A_tmpTable

-- foreach the @A_tmpTable
SET @i = 1;
SET @numrows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @A_tmpTable)
--SELECT @i, @numrows 
IF @numrows > 0
    WHILE (@i <= @numrows)
    BEGIN
        SET @ObjectType = (SELECT TOP 1 ObjectType FROM @A_tmpTable WHERE idx = @i);
        SET @_Guid = (SELECT TOP 1 _Guid FROM @A_tmpTable WHERE idx = @i);
        SET @_oid = (SELECT TOP 1 Oid FROM @A_tmpTable WHERE idx = @i);

        DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM '+@ObjectType+' WHERE OID =''' + @_Guid + ''' AND IsDeleted = 0) 
                SET @found = 1;
            ELSE
                SET @found = 0;
            ';
        -- check if table record exists and save the result in the @found variable
        exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@found bit out', @found out

        IF @found = 0
            INSERT INTO @orphanedA_tmpTable (Oid) VALUES (@_oid);


        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

SELECT * FROM A WHERE Oid IN (SELECT Oid FROM @orphanedA_tmpTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Queries must have statically known structure to be optimized and executed. You can't use dynamic table names.

Join all possible tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON ...
LEFT JOIN C ON ...
LEFT JOIN D ON ...
WHERE
 (B.IsDeleted IS NULL AND C.IsDeleted IS NULL AND D.IsDeleted IS NULL)
 OR (B.IsDeleted = 1 OR C.IsDeleted = 1 OR D.IsDeleted = 1)
```

I think I didn't get the condition exactly right because we need to match on `ObjectType` as well. I'll leave that for you to fix. The important idea is to join all possible tables, though.